Access database locked after any connection
I have a strange problem, and I am not an expert in Access.
On a network, on client PC's, there is an application which uses an Access database located on the server.
We can use the application on multiple machines simultaneously.
On the server, I have a web service developed in .NET, I have a simple method which checks if a record exists or not. If it exists, it updates the record, if not it inserts it. This service is consumed in another application installed on all pcs.
The problem :
-The application which connects directly to the access db is running on any machine.
-The other application which consumes the service installed on the server makes an insert call. The method returns response ok without error.
-The application which connects directly to the access db is blocked! Until closing and reopening, it doesn't respond. As I am not used to working with Access, I searched and as I understand, the service is blocking the database.
But, I couldn't find how to execute a command without blocking the database in C#.
Any idea?
Here is my code of the service.
// Checks if the patient exists :

// My connection string :  

string odbcConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + 
      System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbPath"]) + @"\MyDbName.mdb;";

public TransactionResult PatientExists(string objectID)
{
    TransactionResult result = new TransactionResult();
    using (var oConn = new OleDbConnection(odbcConnection))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var oComm = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Patient WHERE ObjectID = @OBJECTID", oConn))
            {
                oConn.Open();
                oComm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@OBJECTID", objectID));
                var count = Convert.ToInt32(oComm.ExecuteScalar());

                if (count > 0)
                    result.Message = "exists";
                else
                    result.Message = "not-exists";
                oConn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Message = "Error in transaction check patient";
            result.ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                result.InnerExceptionMessage = ex.InnerException.Message;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


//If not Exists :

     
public TransactionResult InsertPatient(Patient pt)
{
    TransactionResult result = new TransactionResult();

    using (var oConn = new OleDbConnection(odbcConnection))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var oComm = new OleDbCommand(
                 "INSERT INTO " +
                 "Patient " +

                 "(" +
                 "[ObjectID]," +
                  ...) " +

                 "VALUES " +

                 "(" +
                 "@ObjectID," +
                  ...) ", oConn))
            {
                if (oComm.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    oComm.Connection.Open();
                }
                oComm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ObjectID", pt.ObjectID));

               ....


               if (Convert.ToBoolean(oComm.ExecuteNonQuery()))
                   result.Message = "Patient has successfully been inserted into the FreeStep Database.";
               else
                   result.Message = "Unknown error.";
           }
       }
       catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
       {
           oConn.Close();
           result.ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;
          result.InnerExceptionMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.Message : "No inner exception.";
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           oConn.Close();
           result.ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;
           result.InnerExceptionMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.Message : "No inner exception.";
       }
       oConn.Close();
       return result;
   }
}

